# Why is React form submitting with empty values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, jpa

I'm learning React, I have this dummy project, back end with Spring Boot, every time I send a POST request it hits the database and generates the auto ID but rest of the fields are empty.  I have changed the form attribute from 'value' to 'defaultValue' because with 'value' it was none editable. I know there are a few threads with similar issues but none is helping me.

```
export function withRouter(Children) {
    return (props) => {
        const match = { params: useParams() };
        return <Children {...props} match={match} />
    }
}
class CategoryEdit extends Component {

    emptyItem = {
        catName: '',
        catDescription: ''
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.url = "http://localhost:8080/categories";
        this.state = {
            item: this.emptyItem
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.match.params.id !== 'add') {
            const category = await (await fetch(`${this.url}/${this.props.match.params.id}`)).json();
            this.setState({ item: category });
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        let item = { ...this.state.item };
        item[name] = value;
        this.setState({ item });
    }

    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { item } = this.state;

        await fetch('http://localhost:8080/categories/add' + (item.id ? '/' + item.id : ''), {
            method: (item.id) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(item),
        });
   };
 
    render() {
        const { item } = this.state;
        const title = <h2>{item.id ? 'Edit Category' : 'Add Category'}</h2>;
        console.log(item);
        return <div>

            <Container>
                <AppNavBar />
                {title}
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="catName"> Category Name</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="catName" id="catName" defaultValue ={item.catName || ''}
                            onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="catName" />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="catDescription">Description</Label>
                        <Input type="text" name="catDescription" id="catDescription" defaultValue ={item.catDescription || ''}
                            onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="catDescription" />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Button color="primary" type="submit">Save</Button>{' '}
                        <Button color="secondary" tag={Link} to="/">Cancel</Button>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        </div>
    }
}
export default withRouter(CategoryEdit);
```

The end points

Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryRestController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService cs;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Category saveCat(Category cat) {
        return cs.addNewCategory(cat);
    }   
}
```

Entity

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer catId;
    private String catName;
    private String catDescription;
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository cr;
    
    public Category addNewCategory(Category category) {
        return cr.save(category);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: If you are learning React in 2023, you should be learning how to use function components with hooks. Classes are no longer the preferred/recommended way of writing React components.

Comment: I've been asked to learn both hence starting with class but you're right most of the examples I've seen  are with function components.

Answer (score 1):

Added your code (with slight modifications to acomodate for TS) to [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-williamson-31xjnu?file=/src/App.tsx) and it works just fine. The attribute should actually be `value`, not `defaultValue`, since it will change you components from uncontrolled to controlled. Also, the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers have no value to you here, they are response headers send from the server, not request headers.
As for the empty values, you may want to check if the api endpoint handler alters the values or expects some other format.

Comment: Thank you Catalin-loan for the detailed reply, you have taught me few 'Dos' and 'Don'ts' but unfortunately I still have the same problem. I have tried to hit the Spring Boot end points with Postman and it works like charm but with React form no data is being transmitted.